# Google query program randomly started giving NullPointerExceptions

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, gson

I am writing a basic program to get the school website of many high schools, but for some reason the program randomly started giving me NullPointerExceptions. By randomly I mean, I tested a set of code that I know worked 100% before this started happening and it no longer works. It is also random in the sense that sometimes the program will return 5 schools and other times it will get a NullPointerException at the first school. What I have currently is shown below and the NullPointer exception happens at System.out.println() and pw.write(). I feel like this means the query isn't returning anything, but it was just a few moments ago.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File infile = new File("inputschools.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(infile);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("outputschools.txt");

    while(in.hasNextLine()){
        String address = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&start=1&q=";
        String query = in.nextLine() + " high school ohio";
        String charset = "UTF-8";

        URL url = new URL(address + URLEncoder.encode(query, charset));
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), charset);
        GoogleResults results = new Gson().fromJson(reader, GoogleResults.class);

        System.out.println("URL: " + results.getResponseData().getResults().get(0).getUrl() + "\n");
        pw.write(results.getResponseData().getResults().get(0).getUrl() + ",");

    }
}
```

}

EDIT: This is the stack trace as requested, but I don't think it will prove very useful.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at GoogleSearch.main(GoogleSearch.java:32)
```

Line 32 is the println() segment.

EDIT2:

This is the code for the actual GoogleResults object. I stepped through the program and for some reason the GoogleResult is null in the second iteration. Can anyone see/think of why this is happening?

```
class GoogleResults{

private ResponseData responseData;
public ResponseData getResponseData() { return responseData; }
public void setResponseData(ResponseData responseData) { this.responseData = responseData; }
public String toString() { return "ResponseData[" + responseData + "]"; }

static class ResponseData {
    private List<Result> results;
    public List<Result> getResults() { return results; }
    public void setResults(List<Result> results) { this.results = results; }
    public String toString() { return "Results[" + results + "]"; }
}

static class Result {
    private String url;
    private String title;
    public String getUrl() { return url; }
    public String getTitle() { return title; }
    public void setUrl(String url) { this.url = url; }
    public void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }
    public String toString() { return "Result[url:" + url +",title:" + title + "]"; }
}
```

}

Comment: Please add the stack trace for the exception. That will help people pin point the problem more easily.

Comment: This line `System.out.println("URL: " + results.getResponseData().getResults().get(0).getUrl() + "\n");`  has a lot of chained method calls, one of which is returning `null`. Break those out into separate lines and check the return values. Maybe if you get an exception, check the corresponding json?

Comment: I figured out what was wrong I think. I think it's a ToS violation to query google like this and they banned me from the api.